# Unable to add / update repositories in lubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, updates, lubuntu, ppa, repository

I am not able to add or update any repositories on my PC.
The following error encountered when I tried updating using
`sudo apt-get update`

```
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/screenlets/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

This error mentions screenlets repository but I am getting the same error when I try to add any repository.I was getting the same error before adding screenlets repository.

---

The following are my specs fetched using neofetch:

OS: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS x86_64
Kernel: 4.15.0-109-generic

Packages: 1701

Shell: bash 4.4.20

CPU: Intel Core 2 Duo E7200 (2) @ 2.306GHz

GPU: Intel 4 Series Chipset

Memory: 1655MiB / 7848MiB

*It is actually lubuntu 18.04*

the question here is that not only I want to add repositories but also update the existing ones.
Also, installing applications from snap is also not working but that could be a different thing altogether.

Comment: Support for that PPA ended with 16.10, and the fact that it's had no maintenance since 2016 means to me, it should not have been added to a modern system.  Did you perform any checks?  as PPA's are 3rd party sources, and security checks are on you. https://launchpad.net/~screenlets/+archive/ubuntu/ppa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Screenlets does not provide version for Ubuntu 18.04, in fact it has not been updated since 16.10 (Yakkety).

#### Abandon screenlets

This will remove Screenlets ppa, effectively get rid of the problem altogether.

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:screenlets/ppa
sudo apt update
```

#### Use old 16.04 source

If you wish to keep using screenlets, a quick workaround would be using the 16.04 (Xenial) source to install Screenlets.

```
sudo sed -i 's/bionic/xenial/g' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/screenlets-ubuntu-ppa-bionic.list
sudo apt update
```

There'll be no error produced, you can now install package provided from screenlets ppa.

**Note that I have not tested this method because it's not something I want to (have to un-)do on my machine**

---

As a side note, you may want to refer to this [nice tutorial](https://www.maravento.com/2018/05/screenlets-en-bionic.html) which explain in depth how to successfully install Screenlets on Ubuntu 18.04 (and 20.04 !).